# How do I iterate the price in parentheses and add it to the total price, My code doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I've found this on google and gave it a go. But it seems as if its not doing anything. it isn't updating the price total area at all, nor is it adding or subtracting.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function doMath() {
        // Capture the entered values of two input boxes
        var my_input1 = document.getElementsByName("case").value;
        var my_input2 = document.getElementsByName("cpu").value;
        var my_input3 = document.getElementsByName("cooling").value;
        var my_input4 = document.getElementsByName("ram").value;
        var my_input5 = document.getElementsByName("gpuchoice").value;
        var my_input6 = document.getElementsByName("storage").value;
        var my_input7 = document.getElementsByName("storage1").value;
        var my_input8 = document.getElementsByName("storage2").value;
        var my_input9 = document.getElementsByName("powersupchoice").value;
        var my_input10 = document.getElementsByName("fans").value;
        var my_input11 = document.getElementsByName("lighting").value;
        var my_input12 = document.getElementsByName("sleeving").value;
        var my_input13 = document.getElementsByName("peripherals").value;
        var my_input14 = document.getElementsByName("headsets").value;
        var my_input15 = document.getElementsByName("controllers").value;
        var my_input16 = document.getElementsByName("wirelessadapter").value;
        // Add them together and display
        var sum = parseInt(my_input1) + parseInt(my_input2) + parseInt(my_input3) + parseInt(my_input4) + parseInt(my_input5) + parseInt(my_input6) + parseInt(my_input7) + parseInt(my_input8) + parseInt(my_input9) + parseInt(my_input10) + parseInt(my_input11) + parseInt(my_input12) + parseInt(my_input13) + parseInt(my_input14) + parseInt(my_input15) + parseInt(my_input16);
      document.getElementsByName("text2").value = sum;
      document.getElementsByName("text2").innerHTML = sum;
    }
      </script>
```

Any advice, or a better way of handling this perhaps?

The code works, but it wont get the data price of storage 1 or storage 2, with those two removed from the sum function it adds the totals of everything else perfect. just not these two inputs.

```
<select name="storage1" id="storage1">
               <option data-productprice="45.00" value="None" selected>None</option>
               <option data-productprice="45.00" value="Crucial MX500 SSD 500 GB (+$0.00)">Crucial MX500 500 GB (+$0.00)</option>
               <option data-productprice="45.00" value="Crucial MX500 SSD 1 TB (+$0.00)">Crucial MX500 1 TB (+$0.00)</option>
               <option data-productprice="45.00" value="Crucial MX500 SSD 2 TB (+$0.00)">Crucial MX500 2 TB (+$0.00)</option>
             </select>
```

here is the JS that is broken with the storage options in sum function, remove the parseFloat(my_input7) everything works great. put it back in and NAN haha

```
function doMath() {
  //var regExp = /\(([^)]+)\)/;
  //var matches = regExp.exec("I expect five hundred dollars ($500).");

  // Capture the entered values of two input boxes
  var my_input1 = document.querySelector('[name=case]:checked').dataset.productprice;
  var my_input2 = document.querySelector('[name=cpu]:checked').dataset.productprice;
  var my_input3 = document.querySelector('[name=cooling]:checked').dataset.productprice;
  var my_input4 = document.querySelector('[name=ram]:checked').dataset.productprice;
  var my_input5 = document.querySelector('[name=gpuchoice]:checked').dataset.productprice;
  var my_input6 = document.querySelector('[name=storage]:checked').dataset.productprice;
  var my_input7 = document.querySelector('[name=storage1]').dataset.productprice;
  var my_input8 = document.querySelector('[name=storage2]').dataset.productprice;
  var my_input9 = document.querySelector('[name=powersupchoice]:checked').dataset.productprice;
  var my_input10 = document.querySelector('[name=fans]:checked').dataset.productprice;
  var my_input11 = document.querySelector('[name=lighting]:checked').dataset.productprice;
  var my_input12 = document.querySelector('[name=sleeving]').dataset.productprice;
  var my_input13 = document.querySelector('[name=peripherals]').dataset.productprice;
  var my_input14 = document.querySelector('[name=headsets]').dataset.productprice;
  var my_input15 = document.querySelector('[name=controllers]').dataset.productprice;
  var my_input16 = document.querySelector('[name=wirelessadapter]').dataset.productprice;
  // Add them together and display
  var sum =  parseFloat(55.00) + parseFloat(50.25) + parseFloat(20.55) + parseFloat(my_input1) + parseFloat(my_input2) + parseFloat(my_input3) + parseFloat(my_input4) + parseFloat(my_input4) + parseFloat(my_input6) + parseFloat(my_input7);
  
  document.getElementById('pricetotal').value = sum;
  document.getElementById('text2').innerHTML = sum;
}
```

I have solved it due to the two wonderful people that posted there answers! I read up on what you guys recommended and ended up using this to fix it due to the select option field.

Code is below :D

```
 function doMath() {
  var my_input1 = document.querySelector('[name=case]:checked').dataset.productprice;
  var my_input2 = document.querySelector('[name=cpu]:checked').dataset.productprice;
  var my_input3 = document.querySelector('[name=cooling]:checked').dataset.productprice;
  var my_input4 = document.querySelector('[name=ram]:checked').dataset.productprice;
  var my_input5 = document.querySelector('[name=gpuchoice]:checked').dataset.productprice;
  var my_input6 = document.querySelector('[name=storage]:checked').dataset.productprice;
  var my_input7 = document.querySelector('[name=storage1]');
  var my_input8 = document.querySelector('[name=storage2]');
  var my_input9 = document.querySelector('[name=powersupchoice]:checked').dataset.productprice;
  var my_input10 = document.querySelector('[name=fans]:checked').dataset.productprice;
  var my_input11 = document.querySelector('[name=lighting]:checked').dataset.productprice;
  var my_input12 = document.querySelector('[name=sleeving]');
  var my_input13 = document.querySelector('[name=peripherals]:checked').dataset.productprice;
  var my_input14 = document.querySelector('[name=headsets]');
  var my_input15 = document.querySelector('[name=controllers]');
  var my_input16 = document.querySelector('[name=wirelessadapter]');
  var valueofssd1 = my_input7.options[my_input7.selectedIndex].dataset.productprice;
  var valueofssd2 = my_input8.options[my_input8.selectedIndex].dataset.productprice;
  var valueofsleeving = my_input12.options[my_input12.selectedIndex].dataset.productprice;
  var valueofheadset = my_input14.options[my_input14.selectedIndex].dataset.productprice;
  var valueofcontroller = my_input15.options[my_input15.selectedIndex].dataset.productprice;
  var valueofadapter = my_input16.options[my_input16.selectedIndex].dataset.productprice;
  // Add them together and display
  var sum = parseFloat(my_input1) + parseFloat(my_input2) + parseFloat(my_input3) + parseFloat(my_input4) + parseFloat(my_input5) + parseFloat(my_input6) + parseFloat(my_input9) + parseFloat(my_input10) + parseFloat(my_input11) + parseFloat(my_input13) + parseFloat(valueofssd1) + parseFloat(valueofssd2) + parseFloat(valueofsleeving) + parseFloat(valueofheadset) + parseFloat(valueofcontroller) + parseFloat(valueofadapter);

  document.getElementById('pricetotal').value = "$" + sum + ".00";
  document.getElementById('text2').innerHTML = "$" + sum + ".00";
}
```

Comment: then answer to how to read the price from a string is RegEx but in this case your fundamental approach will cause you more headaches than it worth so you need to change how you are approaching the problem

Comment: I figured it out, I updated my OP :) Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I write an answer as it's a bit too long for a comment.

There's a lot of mess both in your HTML code and in the way you try to select elements. You have a mix of `<input>` and `<select>` elements in your page, whose values you try to select and sum.

When you select `<input>` elements via `getElementsByName`, you  select indeed a [**NodeList**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList?retiredLocale=it) of elements (there are also some `<h1>` inside!), so you have to *narrow* them to the ones you really need to get their `value`.

The right selections for your elements would be:

```
var my_input1 = document.querySelector('[name=case]:checked').value;
var my_input2 = document.querySelector('[name=cpu]:checked').value;
var my_input3 = document.querySelector('[name=cooling]:checked').value;
var my_input4 = document.querySelector('[name=ram]:checked').value;
var my_input5 = document.querySelector('[name=gpuchoice]:checked').value;
var my_input6 = document.querySelector('[name=storage]:checked').value;
var my_input7 = document.querySelector('[name=storage1]').value;
var my_input8 = document.querySelector('[name=storage2]').value;
var my_input9 = document.querySelector('[name=powersupchoice]:checked').value;
var my_input10 = document.querySelector('[name=fans]:checked').value;
var my_input11 = document.querySelector('[name=lighting]:checked').value;
var my_input12 = document.querySelector('[name=sleeving]').value;
var my_input13 = document.querySelector('[name=peripherals]').value;
var my_input14 = document.querySelector('[name=headsets]').value;
var my_input15 = document.querySelector('[name=controllers]').value;
var my_input16 = document.querySelector('[name=wirelessadapter]').value;
```

Still too much cumbersome to be honest, but at least it selects the right elements.

**But**, also this way it won't work for your purposes. That's because sometimes your `<input>`/`<select>` elements have a value like `value="45"`, some other times they have a value like `value="Moroval Diamond Mesh Case"`; this way, they are not summable:

```
 "45" + "Moroval Diamond Mesh Case" // will yield the string "45Moroval Diamond Mesh Case"
```

That's the exact list of values you would get from my code above:

```
"45" // parseInt() -> 45
"Ryzen 5 3600 (+$0.00)" // parseInt() -> NaN
"Thermaltake TH120 RGB (+$0.00)" // parseInt() -> NaN
"Corsair Vengeance LPX 16 GB (2 x 8 GB) DDR4-3200 Memory (+$0.00)" // parseInt() -> NaN
"XFX Radeon RX 6500 XT 4 GB Speedster QICK 210" // parseInt() -> NaN
"Samsung 970 Evo Plus M2 NVME SSD 500 GB (+$0.00)" // parseInt() =-> NaN
"None" // parseInt() -> NaN
"None" // parseInt() -> NaN
"Corsair CX 650M 650 WATT BRONZE Power Supply (+$0.00)" // parseInt() -> NaN
"Artic P12 Non-RGB Case Fans x3 (+$0)" // parseInt() -> NaN
"No Lighting Selected" // parseInt() -> NaN
"None" // parseInt() -> NaN
undefined // parseInt() -> NaN
"None" // parseInt() -> NaN
"None" // parseInt() -> NaN
"No Wireless Adapter" // parseInt() -> NaN
```

The only number comes from the first selection. Others are strings or `undefined`, so `parseInt()` won't be a number but `NaN` ([Not a Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN)).

**Edit (based on @MikeT comment)**:

<s>It's better to always use numbers for `value` attribute in this case. Something like (random numbers):</s>

Consider that in your `<select>` elements, each `<option>` tag should always have a unique identifier as `value` (to be sure to uniquely identify each option):

```
// select HTML element
<select name="headsets" id="headsets">
    <option value="1">None</option>
    <option value="2">Razer BlackShark V2 Pro 7.1 Wireless (+$100.00)</option>
    <option value="3">HyperX Cloud II 7.1 Wireless (+$95.00)</option>
    <option value="4">Corsair Void RGB Elite 7.1 Wireless (+$87.60)</option>
    <option value="5">Logitech G935 DTS:X 7.1 Wireless (+$156.99)</option>
</select>

// hard-coded array of products to link selected value and price. probably a database-based solution is a better choice
const headsets = [
    { id: 1, description: 'None', price: 0 },
    { id: 2, description: 'Razer BlackShark V2 Pro 7.1 Wireless', price: 100 },
    { id: 3, description: 'HyperX Cloud II 7.1 Wireless', price: 95 },
    { id: 4, description: 'Corsair Void RGB Elite 7.1 Wireless', price: 87.6 },
    { id: 5, description: 'Logitech G935 DTS:X 7.1 Wireless', price: 156.99 },
];

// this is the price to sum
const selectedHeadsetPrice = headsets.find(item => item.id === +document.getElementById('headsets').value).price;
```

Comment: i would strongly disagree with "It's better to always use numbers for value attribute in this case. Something like (random numbers):" the value should always be an unique id that can be used to associate to the exact item selected, then you would have some means of linking that id to a value either by a database or just a code base array

Comment: Totally agree @MikeT.
Wanted only point out the fact that a string is even worse. Of course `value` should only keep unique values. I'd say that the database solution could fit better

Comment: @MikeT I edited my answer based on your comment.

Comment: if your going to hard code the options in the select then the description probably isn't required, but if you are going to dynamically generate the options (almost alwats a good idea with changeable data) then its vital

Comment: I am now getting a NAN on all select fields. If I remove them from the sum function it outputs the totals correctly Then i add these back in and it returns NAN for some reason am i calling the wrong things?

I have added the update problem code to my OP at the bottom

Comment: fixed and updated post to show working code :D thank you guys!!

Answer (score 2):

as @cheesyMan says your html is a mess and you are trying to brute for something that is better handled by finesse

i would aim for something more like this

```
const headsetData = { // preferably this would be read form a database or other not on page source
    "none":{
        display:"None",
        price:0
    },
    "rzp7":{
        display:"Razer BlackShark V2 Pro 7.1 Wireless (+$100.00)",
        price:100
    },
    "hxc7":{
        display:"HyperX Cloud II 7.1 Wireless (+$95.00)",
        price:95
    },
}
```

you could then populate from this list

```
const headsetselect = document.querySelector('select[name=headsets]')

for(const [key, {display} of Object.entries(headsetData)){
    const opt = document.createElement("option");
    opt.value = key;
    opt.innerHTML = display;
    headsetselect .appendChild(opt );
}
```

and then at the calculation stage you would do

```
const headsetselect = document.querySelector('select[name=headsets]')
total += headsetData[headsetselect.value].price
```

though if you follow best practice and `id`s are unique per element then

```
document.getElementById("headset")
```

would be be better than a query selector

edit:
you mention that you also wanted the text for an email

which can also be easilty accompliched like this

```
const product = headsetData[headsetselect.value]
text += `${product.display} ( ${product.price})`
```

Comment: This is great, I made a test page and this worked flawlesssly. With changing the values to numerical values, I lose the functionality of my email form, as it sends me the input value of the items in numerical form now, instead of value=" productname (pricehere)" it now emails me just the monetary value. Could regexp be used to get the price in between the ( )? I found this but i've never messed with regexp before.
var regExp = /\(([^)]+)\)/;
var matches = regExp.exec("I expect five hundred dollars ($500).");

Comment: depends how you are building your email form, however you should be getting the id's not the prices and as you know the id;s you should know which products

Comment: I have it working but trying to get the price of the optional storage options returns NAN, if i remove that it adds everything else just fine. Ive updated my OP to paste in the working code with the storage select issue at the bottom of it

Comment: How do I make my code less of a mess? What exactly am I doing wrong? I'd love to improve!

Comment: if you are assigning ids. make sure that its the only id with that value on the page, if you are using names try to keep them inside a single component such as a form and have them unique inside that container (that way you can select the container then query its content for the unique name), for other options where unique isn't possible use classes, this will also help you with your css as you will already have everything tagged up for styling

Comment: Thank you :) It's been a long time since I've done this, I'm taking your advice and will only assign id's so they are unique and not the same as others, using names in forms is a fantastic idea, and classes for non-unique and for CSS. Just wanna say you're awesome, thanks for the constructive criticism, I usually just get hate D: